# Agora o objeto de discussão é a tag [object]

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Dê uma olhada em [object](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object). Ela fala da palavra-chave? De objetos em geral? Está sendo usado onde queria dizer "orientação a objeto"? Outros motivos?

Uma dica: sempre olhe a primeira pergunta que ele foi usada. Ali mostra a real intenção dela.

Ela precisa existir? Como podemos prevenir que ela seja mal usada? Esse é um caso clássico de *tag* criada com boa intenção, que seu uso inicial foi adequado, mas depois começaram usar errado.

Tenho certeza que ela é mal usada. Precisamos começar arrumar isso. Vamos tirá-la de onde não é necessária **e** não acrescenta nada útil ou colocar uma mais adequada no lugar.

Comment: Como sabes qual é a primeira pergunta? É a mais antiga?

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, claro. Se estiver ordenada pelas recentes, é só pegar a última da lista.

Comment: Tem a tag [objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objetos) acho q poderia ser sinônimo desta tag.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho Noa observação, eu não coloquei pra ver o pessoal está pesquisando ou estou aqui só colocando de alegre e no fim terei que fazer tudo sozinho. Por isso que não sei se ela precisa existir. Se ele ficar ela deve ser de uso bem restrito. NO SO não tem duas. Se um deve morrer, qual das duas deve sobreviver?

Comment: Qual seria um bom uso pra essa tag?